# A really good RichTextBox alternative for .NET

Tags: .net, richtextbox

I'm writing a Windows .NET app that needs a WYSIWYG text editor control that can

- display images inline with the text
- output the text with it's formatting into HTML, XML or something similar (other than RTF)
- preferably free but commercial is fine

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mshtml control (Internet Explorer engine control) will work. You can display images inline, output the text to HTML, and is free.

You can turn on edit mode by setting designMode = true. Here's a [good article](http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=30&skatID=248&artID=6515) detailing how to do that.

Another alternative is to use one of the WPF controls. The WPF RichTextBox is far more powerful than than WinForms RichTextBox. The WPF RTB can be output to a number of different formats and is highly extensible.

Comment: I'm going with the WPF RichTextBox option, which apparently is fairly easy to integrate into an existing winforms app.

Answer (score 2):

You could try txText -
http://www.textcontrol.com/